# Hiring car in Florida under 21 y/o with European license?

Tags: usa, car-rentals, florida, age-limits

From visitflorida.com

> To rent a car you must have your driving license, passport and a credit card. The minimum age for car hire is 21

Is there any way that I can drive a car in Florida as a 19 year old? E.g. by putting someone older than 21 as main driver? Or is it prohibited by state law to drive a car in Florida under 21?

Comment: I think it has more to do with insurance. Not entirely sure. I tried renting a car in America (California) before, being 22 I had to pay quadruple the normal cost. If you can rent a car, I assume you will have to pay jackpot, assuming it's not a law. Also, most companies ask you to have held your license for at least a year. You can put someone else as a main driver, of course, but the legal consequences when they find out can be huge be huge, so I would recommend against that. You'll most likely be better off having someone else drive or taking taxis. PS Americans call it rent, not hire :)

Comment: Hertz will rent to you, but they're one of the more expensive car rental agencies and you'll also have to pay a Young Driver Surcharge.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general you're going to find that car rental agencies will include a surcharge for drivers under 25. In many cases it's actually a matter of law of the minimum age for renting, so it's a matter of company policy *and* the jurisdiction you're in.

After some quick googling, I found the [underage driver surcharge list by state](https://www.budget.com/budgetWeb/html/en/common/agePopUp.html) for Budget car rentals. If you scroll down to Florida, you'll see that for most jurisdictions, there's a surcharge for drivers who are 21-24, which implies that is the minimum rental age in that jurisdiction. However some cities like Orlando indicate a flat "under 25" surcharge, which implies that the minimum age may be 18. If I were in your position, I would find a likely candidate company and city -- such as Budget in Orlando -- and call them.

E-Z Rent a car will rent a car to 18-20 year olds with a $35/day surcharge but there may be additional policies in place based on jurisdiction. [Ref](http://www.e-zrentacar.com/faq)

Avis has a minimum age of 21.

Fox will allow you to rent if aged 19 or older. [Ref](https://www.foxrentacar.com/en/19---up-rental-program.html)

These are just the first few results I found when searching. I'm sure you can find others; see the note below on search terms to use (American English differs slightly from British English in this regard.)

---

For reference in doing further research, we Americans refer to it as a "car rental" (the concept), "renting a car" (the action), and the "rental car" (the result. We tend to use the verb "hire" to refer to persons being employed in tasks rather than objects being 'hired' for a time.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. This might be a dumb question, but if I do rent a car in Orlando, is it possible to drive it all the way to Miami and drop it off there, or am I only allowed to drive within Orlando? (I'd be landing in Orlando so I would be renting the car there anyway)

Comment: @fawningflagellum - There is never a restriction on where you drive (as far as I know), but there may be restrictions on where you are permitted to return the car. If you rent the car in location A and return it in location B, this is often called a "one way rental" and often comes with its own surcharge which can be quite high if you leave the car in a small town or away from an airport/rail station. You'll need to indicate where you intend to return the car when you rent it (which you should do in advance), so they'll let you know if it's not permitted.

Comment: Ok, nice! I'd be returning it in Miami Airport so that'll work.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I've rented cars from some small agencies that restricted where the vehicle could go. One was Florida-only and the other was California plus the route Los Angeles to Las Vegas.

Answer (score 3):

It is not prohibited by law to drive as a 19 year old; however due to insurance premiums most car rental agencies do not rent to under 21 year olds.

You can have someone else rent the car and add you as a secondary driver; there will probably be a premium for this service.

If you are bringing an European license and its not in English you'll have to carry the International Driver's License (which serves as a translation) with it.

Comment: Do you know of any agency that let's you put on a secondary driver of under 21? My travel agency told me they could not find one.

Comment: @fawningflagellum I think those are rare or nonexistent